# Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core when I run project  in local send message function  works well.

```cs
public ActionResult Contact(ContactUs contact)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("MyEmail", "MyPassword");
    mail.From = new MailAddress(contact.Email);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmail"));
    mail.Subject = "Mail From Website ";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string body = "Sender Name : " + contact.Name + "<br>" +
                    "Email :  " + contact.Email + "<br>" +
                    "Telephone : " + contact.Telephone + "<br>" +
                    "Messege :: <b>" + contact.Message + "</b>";
    mail.Body = body;

    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
    TempData["SuccessfulSende"] = "Succesfully ";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

After I host the project  to server when I send message I get this error:

> Development Mode
> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's happening is that you've got an unhandled exception. But exceptions can reveal sensitive information, so it's not showing it by default. That's good for security. The error page should explain how to get the actual error. And in any decent application, you should add logging so that all unhandled exceptions can be reviewed by developers without needing to have the website directly display the error.

Comment: thank you for your response . when i run project in local i dont get any error and function works well but in host i get the error

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question. Repeating yourself doesn't provide any value. You can follow the directions on the error page to see the full exception details in your browser, or you can add proper logging to your application. Do you understand your options? Are you having trouble picking and implementing one of those options?

Comment: ahh ok i get this when i post method 500 (Internal Server Error) Contact.1 in browser dev env

Comment: Yes, that's not unexpected given the other behavior you described. Do you understand the options I described for getting the exception details?

Comment: yes thank you very much